# Read contents of file on web server with ajax sync methoed may freezing the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

On my web site, I need to read files contents (which is generated by php) from web server, and assigned the contents to an html tag.

The ajax read file by default is aync, the code for assign the value to the html tag is already passed before the file contents has been successfully read.

To get over the problem, use the ajax async methoed.

$.ajax({
           url: 'file_relative_path',
           async: false,
           success: function (data){                                                                         console.log('description from file contents:'+data);
           desc=data;
           }
});

Wait for for read file success before assign the file contents to variable solve the problem, but it might result in an other issue, since the code has to wait for the read file finished.

Any suggestion?

Comment: well synchronous calls lock the page.... that is what happens. That is why people say not to use them. So you need to use promises or callbacks...

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: He's referring to "async: false"

Comment: I put around 50 markers representing 50 sights on the google map, each makers come with a inforwindow, inforwindow is populated by html tags which include a sight description and a bounch of url link which link to inmages from the external web site. Javascript reading the filename from folder

Answer (score 0):

I put around 50 markers representing 50 sights on the google map, each makers come with a inforwindow, inforwindow is populated by html tags which include a sight description and a bunch of url which linked to images from the external web site. The urls are the file name in the sights folder. Those images are belong to the site. I put the description of each image in the correspondent file, and the javascript need to  read the file into string and the string is assigned to image title which could be displayed for each images. I need to use async method to wait for the file read into the string and assign to the html tag. this hold the whole process and even hold the google map showing on the page. I did some modify and move add markers out side the initialize function which allow the google map loaded first and then markers add to the page one by one, this make the page more responsive. But read file to string with asyc still hold the process, i might considering let php read the file to string and passed to javescript, this might make things more smoth.